# Ruby Merging Two Arrays into One

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, iterator

Here is my situation. I have 2 Arrays

```
@names = ["Tom", "Harry", "John"]

@emails = ["tom@gmail.com", "h@gmail.com", "j@gmail.com"]
```

I want to combine these two into some Array/Hash called `@list` so I can then iterate in my view something like this:

```
<% @list.each do |item| %>
<%= item.name %><br>
<%= item.email %><br>
<% end %>
```

I'm having trouble understanding how I can achieve this goal. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 54):

```
@names  = ["Tom", "Harry", "John"]
@emails = ["tom@gmail.com", "h@gmail.com", "j@gmail.com"]

@list = @names.zip( @emails )
#=> [["Tom", "tom@gmail.com"], ["Harry", "h@gmail.com"], ["John", "j@gmail.com"]]

@list.each do |name,email|
  # When a block is passed an array you can automatically "destructure"
  # the array parts into named variables. Yay for Ruby!
  p "#{name} <#{email}>"
end
#=> "Tom <tom@gmail.com>"
#=> "Harry <h@gmail.com>"
#=> "John <j@gmail.com>"

@urls = ["yahoo.com", "ebay.com", "google.com"]

# Zipping multiple arrays together
@names.zip( @emails, @urls ).each do |name,email,url|
  p "#{name} <#{email}> :: #{url}"
end
#=> "Tom <tom@gmail.com> :: yahoo.com"
#=> "Harry <h@gmail.com> :: ebay.com"
#=> "John <j@gmail.com> :: google.com"
```

Comment: Aha! So *this* is what `zip` is for! It somehow never really entered my standard toolbox. Nice. +1

Comment: Would this solution still be applicable I added another instance variable called @urls = ["yahoo.com", "ebay.com", "google.com"].

Comment: @lou1221 Yes; see the updated answer above. `Array#zip` can take an arbitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score 18):

Just to be different:

```
[@names, @emails, @urls].transpose.each do |name, email, url|
  # . . .
end
```

This is similar to what [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-zip) does except that in this case there won't be any nil padding of short rows; if something is missing an exception will be raised.

Comment: The tip on transpose is great. Thanks for posting this

Comment: I was looking for Python's `zip(*arrays)`. This is it!

Answer (score 7):

```
Hash[*names.zip(emails).flatten]
```

This will give you a hash with name => email.

Comment: Works for this situation, but future readers beware: it is not a general solution, since if either `names` or `emails` were arrays that contained arrays, `flatten` would run recursively.

Comment: Under Ruby 1.9 you can simply do: `Hash[ names.zip(emails) ]`

Comment: flatten(1) will prevent recursion, if desired.

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes, but `Array#flatten` does not accept arguments in 1.8.6; if you can use `flatten(1)` then you can use the form of `Hash.[]` that does not require flattening. _(Both are available in 1.8.7 in addition to 1.9.)_

Comment: or `names.zip(emails).to_h`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` to zip together the two arrays and then `map` to create `Item` objects from the name-email-pairs. Assuming you have an `Item` class whose `initialize` methods accepts a hash, the code would look like this:

```
@list = @names.zip(@emails).map do |name, email|
  Item.new(:name => name, :email => email)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
Hash[@names.zip(@emails)]
```

You have two arrays
@names = ["Tom", "Harry", "John"]

@emails = ["tom@gmail.com", "h@gmail.com", "j@gmail.com"]

@names.zip(@emails) it merge @emails to the @names associated with their index like below
 [["Tom", "tom@gmail.com"], ["Harry", "h@gmail.com"], ["John", "j@gmail.com"]]

Now we can convert this array into hash using 
Hash[@names.zip(@emails)]