# How to iterate with two arrays

Tags: ruby, loops, foreach

How to iterate in arrays using ruby?

```
array1 = [1,2,3]
array2 = ["Birthday", "Anniversary" , "Graduation"]
```

Comment: Use `zip` as described in the duplicate question [Ruby Merging Two Arrays into One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572992/ruby-merging-two-arrays-into-one); alternatively you can use (ick) `each_with_index`.

Comment: No offence but I think you need a beginner book.

Comment: Recommend you read the book 'Everyday scripting with ruby" it's a great tester oriented introduction to Ruby.  Also Zeljko's 'Watir Book'

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a 2D array.

```
Dates = [["1", "Birthday"],["2", "Anniversary"],["2", "Graduation"]]

Dates.each do |number, event|
 @browser.checkbox(:text => number).click
 @browser.link(:text => event).click
end
```

You will have to fill in the blanks, but that format is the meat of the issue.  I also recommend a beginner Ruby and WATIR book.

As mentioned above, zip would be a good method to combine the two separate arrays, but I imagined you were creating them manually so instead you could just create a 2D array manually.

Answer (score 2):

```
array1.zip(array2).each { |num, word| puts "#{num}: #{word}" }
# Output:
1: Birthday
2: Anniversary
3: Graduation
```