# Logstash MySQL combine multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

Using logstash

Data

```
| field01           | field02   |
|q01, q02, q03      |2, 3, 4    |
|q01, q03           |2, 4       |
|q01, q03, q04, q05 |2, 4, 5, 6 |
....
```

I want to merge two arrays using logstash filter

```
filter {
    mutate {
        split => { "field01" => "," }
        split => { "field02" => "," }
        add_field => {????} // how should I write it?
    }
}
```

result

```
data : [
{ 
    field01 : q01,
    field02 : 2
}, 
{ 
    field01 : q02,
    field02 : 3
}, 
...
```

how should I write it to get the desired result?

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick the individual field values

```
"field01","%{[field01][0]}"
"field02","%{[field02][0]}"
```

But since the amount can vary, I'm not sure mutate split can deal with enumeration, I would use a bit of ruby instead, then you can zip two arrays.

[Ruby Merging Two Arrays into One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572992/ruby-merging-two-arrays-into-one#4573040)